# Sort value of HashMap in descending order by list size in Java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have following HashMap.

```
Map<String, List<String>> teamsPerLocation = new HashMap<String, List<String>>()
```

I want to sort the HashMap in descending order by the size of the value list.

Example:

```
// Before sorting
"New York" -> ["Team1", "Team2"]        // 2 teams
"Berlin" -> ["Team3", "Team4", "Team5"] // 3 teams
"Boston" -> ["Team6"]                   // 1 team

// After sorting
"Berlin" -> ["Team3", "Team4", "Team5"] // 3 teams
"New York" -> ["Team1", "Team2"]        // 2 teams
"Boston" -> ["Team6"]                   // 1 team
```

I need a sorted Map at the end.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html: *" This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. "* - If you want an ordered Map a HashMap really isn't the way to go. Consider using a  sortable map like TreeMap.

Comment: I think you should use a `SortedMap` implementation, for example, `TreeMap`.

Comment: @RafaelGuillen `SortedMap` can only sort by keys.

Comment: "I want to sort the HashMap in descending order" do you want a Map with a specific iteration order; or do you merely need to iterate the keys in that order once?

Comment: I need a Map with the descending order. I think the "duplicate" question marked answer is not what I need.
I need a map with DESCENDING order. That is my problem at the moment.

Comment: @AndyTurner you can provide a comparator in the `SortedMap` constructor...

Comment: Something like this:

final Map<String, List<String>> unsortedMap = new HashMap<>();
    unsortedMap.put("New York", List.of("Team1", "Team2"));

    unsortedMap.put("Berlin", List.of("Team3", "Team4", "Team5"));
    unsortedMap.put("Boston", List.of("Team6"));

    Comparator<String> comparator = (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(unsortedMap.get(o2).size(), unsortedMap.get(o1).size());
    SortedMap<String, List<String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(comparator);

    sortedMap.putAll(unsortedMap);

Comment: @RafaelGuillen Thank you. This nearly solves my problem. Unfortunately, entries with the same list size are omitted. So if we have 4 entries. And of these there are 3 entries that have a list size of 10. Then only two entries are included in the sortedMap. The rest will be omitted.

Comment: Yes it's just the idea, you should manage empty/null lists and also extend the comparison to keys when list sizes are equal, something like this:
Comparator<String> comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
      int result = Integer.compare(unsortedMap.get(o2).size(), unsortedMap.get(o1).size());
      return result == 0 ? o1.compareTo(o2) : result;
    };